# Access denied to ClearDB database using Python/Django on Heroku

Tags: python, mysql, django, heroku

I'm trying to build a webapp on Heroku using Python/Django, and I just followed the tutorial to set up a Django project and push it to Heroku.  However, I can never even get to the normal Django "It worked!" screen.  Of course, that is because when I check `heroku ps`, there are never any processes running.  There is no `Procfile` but according to the tutorial, that shouldn't matter for a Django app.

When I run `heroku run python manage.py runserver`, the following error occurs:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <dja
ngo.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x1ff819
0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/com
mands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/bas
e.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/val
idation.py", line 103, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/v
alidation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/b
ase.py", line 411, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init_
_.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/b
ase.py", line 387, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line
 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", l
ine 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user '<user>
'@'%' to database 'heroku_<####################>?reconnect=true'")
```

I did already set my `DATABASE_URL` to the value of `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`.  Also, in the Django `settings.py`, I added as instructed:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular error was fixed after calling ClearDB.  Turns out that the `?reconnect=true` is only for Rails apps, and should be removed from the `DATABASE_URL` for Django apps.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more?